# Invalid API key in Disqus API

Tags: disqus

I'm struggling to get the disqus API to work when I run it with `curl`. It works fine using the Console:

[image: console_works]

When I use `curl` on the command line, I get an "Invalid API key" error:

[image: command_line_no_go]

I *think* I'm using the correct API key as shown below:

[image]

I must be missing something simple. Help?!

Comment: Just a side note on the question; screenshot was perfect for diagnosing the issue, but having screenshot instead of copy/pasteable text meant transcribing the screenshot to reproduce it. Consider including actual text (can use the "code" markup) as well next time. Cheers, and thanks for Mothur!

Comment: Thanks for the feedback - I thought I was botching something with the api key and didn't want to put it in a text format. Altho I guess I should probably reset the key at this point anyway.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You've got double "?" for the get params, so it's ignoring the second one, which contains your API key.

[image: double q mark]

You should use a "&" for further params. So:

```
?firstparam=foo&secondparam=bar
```

Working example (with my key redacted):

```
pst@SAGAN:~$ curl "https://disqus.com/api/3.0/categories/list.json?forum=biorxivstage&api_key=HfHklsMTXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX"
{"cursor":{"prev":null,"hasNext":false,"next":"2674863:25:0","hasPrev":false,"total":null,"id":"2674863:25:0","more":false},"code":0,"response":[{"isDefault":true,"title":"General","order":0,"forum":"biorxivstage","id":"2674863"}]}
```

Comment: Ugh, thanks - knew it had to be something simple - thanks!